# Does node.js cron affect system performance

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

I want to use cron module ([later](http://bunkat.github.io/later/), [node-cron](https://github.com/ncb000gt/node-cron) etc.) in my node server to schedule jobs. The jobs are notifications (eg. email) sent to a user to update his profile picture if he hasen't done so after 1 hour of signup. I am using `later` module to schedule tasks when user signs up, to be executed 1 hour after to check whether he has uploaded profile picture, and send notification if not. My questions are:
1. Will having a large number of scheduled jobs affect server performance?
2. What is the best way to schedule large number of jobs without affecting the system performance?

Comment: unix has a built-in thing called cron.  use that to schedule the running of scripts at intervals. no need to re-invent this in javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to say whether a large number will affect system performance, since it depends an aweful lot on what they're doing and how they're doing it, as well as how many end up hitting at one time, etc.

That said, my opinion is that using this sort of thing for managing the sorts of things you're describing will severely limit your scalability, as each one is scoped to the application instance (so if you want to scale horizontally, each manages they're own; if one crashes w/o sending notifications out, what happens?  etc).

I think you're far better off using some kind of distributed task manager, based perhaps on a Redis queue or similar.  Your web app posts jobs to that, and a separate process or processes can handle running tasks when they expire.  There's a few modules for this sort of thing, `kue` is the one I've played with.

Comment: `kue` sounds like a good idea. But I did not understand what you ment by "separate process or processes can handle running tasks when they expire". Can you eleborate on this?

Comment: That was poorly worded.  I just meant that you can create a more scalable application by separating out functionality.  Have one app that does the web functionality. When it needs a job done, it pops it onto a queue of some kind, and another process pops jobs off the queue when they're due to be done and runs them w/o affecting the web app.

Comment: Perhaps you can limit the amount of cron jobs by creating batches of emails that you collect every hour and sending that "email-to" list to a 3rd party like Sendgrid. Though in this case, if the code that crawls your DB for missing profile pictures is intensive, you'll still be slowed down. A "part-way" solution that may be useful until you actually scale.